# In statistics what does NA stand for?

Tags: notation, abbreviation

I understand that NA means data is missing, null or not present.  But what do the letters NA stand for?  "Not Available"?

Comment: The really important matter is the meaning of it. Whether a missing is "not known value" (and thence NA*0=0) or "unprovided entry" (and thence NA*0=NA).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In datasets, NA can mean:

- "*Not Available*": e.g. the sensor was down at the time of the measure,
- "*Not Applicable*": e.g. when asking a bachelor the name of his wife,
- "*No Answer*": e.g. the respondent to a questionnaire skipped a question.